# Input mask for telephone number in jQuery

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I am starter in jQuery. 
I have a text-box on my page in that i need to enter Telephone number such as `+44(0) 161 738 1266`. Now as per example i need to allow **+ , - , numeric , space**. except that it should ignore other input. 
I need to Take input mask as well. Can somebody suggest me.

Comment: please show some code

Comment: I have used this but not as pexpected  $.mask.definitions['h'] = "[+-0-9]";               $("#DirectDialTelephoneNumber").mask("h(h)hhhhhhhh");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following :

```
jQuery(function($){
   $.mask.definitions['~']='[+]';
   $("#phonenumber").mask("~99(9) 999 999 9999");
});
```

Here :

**9** - Represents a numeric character (0-9)

**~** - creating a own mask definition. you can put custom values here as per your need.

For more information, you can refer : http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#usage

Answer (score 0):

That would do it. It's not most elegant solution, but it is inline and now worries one.

```
onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 || event.charCode==32 || event.charCode==43 || event.charCode==45)"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V8dHr/1/

You just return false if pressed key`s charCode is not numeric, space, plus or minus

What comes to input mask; there's easy plugin for handling it: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
It will cover Your needs i guess :)

Answer (score 0):

I have attached a fiddle satisfying your conditions..i hope its useful.

http://jsfiddle.net/TLck2/

html :

```
<input type="text" id="phone"/>
```

script:

$("#phone").mask("99(9) 999-999-9999");